# Where on Earth does the wind only blow one way?

Tags: wind, mapping

Is there a place on Earth that if the wind is blowing its only blowing (here is the twist) in the same direction from the ground to 53 km high?

Comment: You may want to read up on [thermal wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_wind).  Essentially, what you're asking for is impossible.

Comment: The problem for bounties I see is the points are not returned when there is no answer, so nobodody sometimes wins. Top users can do not worry a lot about it. Mysef I offered some of them and it took me some months to recover my reputation, so I am not going to offer more until I reach 2k or so, but you are free to do what you want Muze. If it is your question you may recover some of them because of the positives.

Comment: @Universal_learner  Understood. You're fine. Thanks